# How to number ALL equations by default?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

Suppose I want all the equations in my document to be numbered. (Please don't ask me why.)

Is there a global option that turns numbering on, so I can simply write 
`\[ E=mc^2 \]` instead of `\begin{equation} E=mc^2 \end{equation}`?

Comment: No, use search and replace in your editor

Comment: Fortunately he wants to replace `\[ \]` not `$$ $$`, so find/replace could be easier.

Comment: If you only want to change ``\[`` and ``\]`` with ``\begin{equation}`` and ``\end{equation}`` respectively, maybe you could use ``\renewcommand\[{\begin{equation}}`` and ``\renewcommand\]{\end{equation}}``.

Comment: Are you using any `align*` environments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd prefer using `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, to be honest.

Since `amsmath` has, at the very end,

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
```

you can just change this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\[\relax \let\]\relax % avoid warnings in the log file
\DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation}}

\begin{document}

This equation will be numbered
\[
1+1=2
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]